# Detect homebrew vs osx python

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm currently having a problem detecting whether a user has installed python through homebrew or is just using the default OSX python. I need to be able to do this because one of the dependencies for my code is a c library that is typically installed in /usr/local/. It turns out the homebrew python will look in this directory by default, but standard OSX python will not. The first thing that I did is the following.

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin' and sys.executable == '/usr/bin/python':
    # Add the paths for /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include
```

This works just fine by default, but it does not work if the users OSX python is not in the standard location. In particular I want people to be able to use virtualenv to install this dependency and if they do that then the path to the OSX python will be different than '/usr/bin/python'. Does anyone know of a good way to detect homebrew python vs osx python?

Comment: How are you using the C library, and what are you adding the paths _to_? And is there a reason you can't just always add them?

Comment: Also, instead of looking at where the library is "typically installed", why not look for the library in the standard configure/setup.py/etc. ways? (Search $PATH, search standard extra paths, run pkgconfig, allow the user to specify it with a configure argument, …)

Comment: Rather than worrying about homebrew vs stock install, why not just check for the actual library is? if os.path.isfile('/usr/local/lib/mylib.lib'): etc...